# SQL filter unique and return total

Tags: sql

I have two following tables:

```
products_table

id name
1  productA
2  productB
3  productC
```

```
inventory_table

id  product_id amount
1   1          200
2   1          300
3   2          100
4   3          200
5   2          500
```

And the result I would like to get is

```
name       total
productA   500
productB   600
productC   200
```

How could this be achieved using sql query?

Comment: You don't need to "filter", you need to "aggregate".  Using `GROUP BY` allows you to return just one row per 'group' (in your case a group being all rows with the same id, or same name).  Then using `SUM()` allows you to total up the amounts across all rows within each 'group'.

Comment: A simple search would return dozens of answers to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems easy, first subSELECT query makes sums, parent one joins the names.

```
SELECT pt.name, n.total
FROM 
(SELECT SUM(it.amount) as total, it.product_id
FROM inventory_table it
GROUP BY it.productID) n JOIN
products_table pt ON pt.id = n.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try joining the two tables and use aggregation as

```
SELECT 
          p.name,
          SUM(i.amount)
FROM product_table as p
LEFT JOIN inventory_table as i
        ON p.id = i.product_id
GROUP by p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `inner join` between the two tables, grouping by each Product and summing all its values.

```
select p.[name], Sum(i.amount) Amount
from product_table p join inventory_table i on i.product_id=p.id
group by p.[name]
```